# Finding a benchmark result

Tags: laptop

I have seen benchmark results from Geekbench https://browser.geekbench.com/ and also from Passmarks. But I would like to see the benchmark results of a given model  (say Dell Precision with ... configuration). Where can I find these results?

Comment: I appreciate that you're trying to figure out what's best for yourself, but we'd actually like a little more context so we can help you! Why are you trying to find the results of a given laptop? If it's to choose a laptop for a specific purpose, give us some more background on what your use case is so we can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find it on [notebookcheck](https://www.notebookcheck.net), but if you don't, simply look at similar laptops. The cooling system may change a bit the performance, but you can see that in reviews and then evaluate if your model might be slightly better/worse that the benchmark you found.